# Write to a Google Doc using Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I am looking to create and write content into a Google Drive Doc.

I have the create a drive doc step down, but aren't able to post my content.

### Code to create file test doc

```
 function createNewFile() {
      gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {

        var request = gapi.client.request({
          'path': '/drive/v2/files',
          'method': 'POST',
          'body': {
            "title": "Test.doc",
            "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
            "description": "Some"
          }
        });

        request.execute(function(resp) {
          console.log(resp);
          updateFile(resp.id, "Test TEXT");
        });
      });
    }
```

### Code to add contents to the newly created google doc

```
function updateFile(fileId, text, callback) {

  const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
  const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

  var contentType = "text/html";
  var metadata = {
    'mimeType': contentType,
  };

  var multipartRequestBody =
    delimiter + 'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
    JSON.stringify(metadata) +
    delimiter + 'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' + '\r\n' +
    text +
    close_delim;

  if (!callback) {
    callback = function(file) {
      console.log("Update Complete ", file)
    };
  }

  gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
    'method': 'PUT',
    'params': {
      'fileId': fileId,
      'uploadType': 'multipart'
    },
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
    },
    'body': multipartRequestBody,
    callback: callback,
  });
}
```

Comment: what JavaScript framework are you using? You do realise you can do the create and content upload in a single transaction (no need for a separate Insert then Update)? Try adding 'convert:true' to your PUT params.

Comment: I tried to put it to my PUT params, but it didn't work.[ 'params': {'fileId': fileId, 'uploadType': 'multipart', 'convert' : 'true'}]

Comment: I wasn't using and javascript framework, is there a framework that would make this easier? I couldn't find anything in Google Drive API w/ examples of how to do this.

Comment: I asked about the framework because I'm working on a library for AngularJS which will do this for you. In the meantime, I've pasted the http into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the POST and UPDATE should look like. You can use your browser console to check what you are doing differently.

**Insert**

```
Request URL:https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/
Request Method:POST

content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8

{title: "delmexxx-0", mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.document"}
```

**Upload**

```
Request URL:https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/
18ECXade2ZfLeo?
convert=true&uploadType=media
Request Method:PUT

content-type: text/plain

some content that will become a google doc
```